# errorClass'in superset when filtering a druid query from the dashboard

Tags: filtering, dashboard, apache-superset, druid

The error "Error: 'errorClass'in superset when filtering a druid query from the dashboard".
it only fails if I apply filters and remove the limit as said in algin post, but it still fails.

The error "Error: 'errorClass'in superset when filtering a druid query from the dashboard".
it only fails if I apply filters and remove the limit as said in algin post, but it still fails.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ekj.png)